# Premiere: Make music sound like it's coming from huge speakers?

Tags: premiere, audio, effects, filter

**The problem with my clip:**

It was recorded on a fashion show and my recording for some reason stopped, but I quickly restarted it, so approximately 2 seconds are missing. On the visuals, not much was happening at that moment, so a cut is not that noticable luckily.

**BUT:** music was playing in the background, so it doesn't matter how I cut, in the audio, you obviously hear the cut. My solution for this problem is to download the original song, bring it to Premiere, put it in place between/under the 2 pieces of clip.

**QUESTION:**
I need this audio to sound like it was recorded "on-set", like the song was played on a huge speaker in a 10m x 20m hall. I tried the audio effect highpass, but with that, it sounds like it was played on a phone, since it eliminates lower frequencies. I tried a few other filters, but since I'm not really into that topic, I couldn't make it convincing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Replicating an environment can be a very complex process and rarely convincing enough. Music on fashion shows tend to be rhythmic, any chance you can't splice in an earlier/later part to fill the gap? Could you share a snippet audio with the problem? (short enough to fall under fair-use).

Comment: We really need a half minute each side of the problem; use YouTube  UnListed, or DropBox, etc. --- You need the audio effect "lowpass" for big speakers, highpass will be tinny (as you discovered) --- To fix be prepared to cut a bit more than you wanted (thus the need for a 1/2 minute each side, at least). Cut it so the music plays, it cuts, and then the next scene jumps (along with the music) to the next Bar (a music term); the visual jump will be obvious but the music will be smoother and less jarring. Need an actual exact answer?, let's see the clip.

Comment: You might be able to use the existing audio and the [Audio Remix feature in Audition](https://theblog.adobe.com/audition-deep-dive-remix-automatically-rearrange-any-song-to-fit-any-duration/) to fill in the gap. This should work well with a steady, repetitive beat. It might not be suitable if there is a lot of background noise.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck by sampling a bit of the video's audio from another point, and splicing that in.  The tone will be dead-on consistent.  You just have to find a point in the song where it basically repeats itself (or close enough).  If you lost *verse* lyrics, this gets much more problematic fast.  But if you lost chorus, or instrumental bridge, intro, or outro, you could make a patch that manages to not distract.  It the song was well-known, a forced splice will be more evident, but might not seem *your* doing (you know?).  At the other extreme, if the song is house music, you're golden: no one will know what it was supposed to do for those two seconds.

Comment: Of course, you need to flange the volume cross-overs between original and splice, cleanly, by ear, or it will still scream out its presence.  I find doing that with manual adjustment of volume levels (with the audio files/clips overlapping on separate audio tracks) works better than using the automated tools for volume crossover at a splice edge.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for software that implements the "LMS algorithm" for echo compensation and let it "compensate" the "echo" from the original track in the available parts of your recording.  The sign-reversed "compensation" will fit well in the gap you have to fill.

Sorry, I just know the technology to use, not which end user tools are generally available implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding a reverb effect on the original audio. Something like a big hall or church setting, tweaking with the parameters (a small change can have huge effect !) and blending level might sound "realistic". It will probably work better than just high or low pass.
Although you might also try to apply some EQ on the reverb, it works usually well to shape the reverb sound.

There are a lot of free VSTs that simulate reverb, you might have to try several to find one you like.
I use a lot [Variety Of Sounds epicVerb](https://varietyofsound.wordpress.com/downloads/) for music production, not sure how it would work as an prominent effect.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers!
Honestly, I didn't really want to download new programs and stuff so I worked in Premiere and finally I managed to make it sound decent enough.
I worked with a couple of audio effects:
1. I used a Convolution Reverb with the Classroom preset and a little bit of tweaking.
2. Then I applied a Fill left with right, since the CV made the singer's voice sound too much to the left due to the mixing.
3. EQ: I turned a little bit down the higher frequencies.
4. I added a Bass boost of 3 dB.

This solution probably doesn't work that well in other scenarios, but it made convincing-enough results for me this time, but I'll try out your advices in the future.

Thanks!
AJ